# What happened when a waiting process (in semaphore queue) receives a signal from another process?

Tags: c, linux, signals, fork, ipc

I'm doing a school project: I have to manage many processes. After they are generated by parent (wht fork()) and launched with execve, they have to communicate with each others and they work perfectly.
The project includes 2 files.c, one of the father (who creates the children) and the other with the children's code.
The problem occurs when I have many queuing and waiting processes that want to access a critical section (where i have decided to implement a mutex semaphore)

The code is similar to:

```
 decrease_semaphore

 //start critical section

 kill(pid,signal)  /*try to send a signal to a probably queuing  process at the same semaphore*/
 increase_semaphore
 //end of critical section
```

The signal sent is captured by a handler written by me.

So, what happens to the queuing process to which the signal is sent?
Does he receive it and leave the waiting queue, executing the handler?

Or does it stay in the queue and execute the handler after it manages to access the critical section?

sorry for any inaccuracies, I recently started writing in c :)

Comment: What kind of semaphore (SysV? POSIX?)?  Can we see the semaphore code?  Most importantly, what happens when you try it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 'sem_wait', and a signal is received (and is not blocked), the sem_wait will return -1 and set errno to EINTR. This can be used to distinguish between other failures (e.g., ETIMEDOUT).